# VB.NET getting date format from date

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, formatting

I need to extract the dateformat from a given date. How am I suppose to do that. Please help.

Comment: I agree with @Mitch, this is very unclear. Do you have a `String` containing a date and you want to figure out what date format (if any) it has, or do you have a `DateTime` value (in which case *it doesn't have a format* in itself)?

Comment: @Mitch - Suppose there is a date of format "1/31/2011 6:00:00 AM". Now how would I get the dateformat out of this date. Like this date should return format "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt".

Comment: imagining for a second that you're dealing with a string, as in your "1/31/2011 6:00:00 AM" example, but that it's actually "1/2/2011 6:00:00 AM". How are we meant to know if that's M/d/yyyy or d/M/yyyy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of dates are built like this:

```
xsysz
```

Where s is a separator that can be `'/', '.', ' '` or even `''`. `x`, `y` and `z` are digits. The problem is that you cannot solve the date format for every possible date because of its ambiguity:

```
Example: 3-2-2010 

Germany: 3rd February 2010
USA: 2nd March 2010
```

You need additional information (is there any separator?) or some preconditions (year-month-day or year-day-month?) in order to be able to do that. (Same for time... of course)

If you have this preconditions, so you might try with regular expressions. DateTime isn't able to do that for you.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. When I use Date.ParseExact with dateformat then only I know what format it is using. Otherwise truly there is know way to understand the same. But I was wondering how the CLR does it when you pass a string as parameter in Convert.ToDateTime() method.

Comment: @Soham - I believe it uses the default settings for the current culture you are running in.

Comment: @Soham @Paddy Paddy is correct. `Convert.ToDateTime(value)` uses the settings from the current culture, just like the documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) admittedly in a roundabout way: "the return value is the result of invoking the `DateTime.Parse` method on `value` using the formatting information in a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object that is initialized **for the current culture**"

Comment: @MarkJ - The info was helpful. Thanks.